# extract an apk file from my phone with computer

Tags: apk

I have a custom app on a broken phone and I need to transfer it to my new phone
I cannot install any apps on my old phone 
Is there a way I can connect the phone to my pc and extract the apk file?

Comment: for that alteast your phone OS needs to boot  on

Comment: You might get a better reception to this question on https://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

You can use the adb even for unrooted devices:

```
adb shell pm list packages
adb shell pm path com.example.someapp
```

The output will look something like this: package:/data/app/com.example.someapp-2.apk

```
adb pull /data/app/com.example.someapp-2.apk path/to/desired/destination
```

Comment: I had forgotten the "adb shell pm path" command - this answer saved me. The base apk was in /data/app/xxxx/package-name-xxx/ and I had been trying in vain to access /data/data/package-name/ which is *not* accessible on non-rooted devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to connect with `adb` you should be able to.

Here is a pretty in depth guide which covers it all - https://androidquest.wordpress.com/2014/09/18/backup-applications-on-android-phone-with-adb/